# How to scroll ListView horizontally with mouse weel ? Flutter - Web

Tags: flutter, listview, flutter-web

I am build a web app with flutter. As in the normal web development we can scroll the page horizontally or vertically with the mouse but in the flutter web the page scrolls vertically not horizontally. My question can we scroll horizontally in flutter web ?

Comment: I'm also having the same issue :(